# When I login, I see "You have mail.", but /var/mail/<username> is empty

Tags: server, mail

I have a Ubuntu 14.04LTS installed on VPS.
I have noticed that when I login I see greeting saying "You have mail", but 
    cat /var/mail/myusername
returns empty string, i.e. the file is empty.
I have configured Postfix virtual mail boxes and Dovecot, following [this tutorial](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-mail-server-ubuntu-14-04/). May be I did something wrong that affects the system mails?

I hope somebody can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe there is an environment variable that points to your mailbox.  Check that out and ensure that it is pointing to the right place for YOUR mailbox.